# Bitmap appears off screen

Tags: java, bitmap

I have a game where the user must collect the blobs that come at them. The blobs are bitmaps. The problem I'm having is that some of the blobs come from outside the screens bounds. So, for example, the bottom part of the blob would appear at the very top of the screen, so I wouldn't be able to see the full bitmap. I want it to where they just come in between the top and bottom part of the screen and not outside it. My question is, can anybody help me in making the blobs only appear on screen? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Just to note*:
`blobOffsetY` = bottom edge coordinate of blob.

My code:

```java
for (int j = 0; j < AppConstants.numberOfBlobs; j++) {
    if (blobs.get(j).getBlobX() < -AppConstants.getBitmapBank().getBlobWidth()) {
        blobs.get(j).setBlobX(blobs.get(j).getBlobX() +
                              AppConstants.numberOfBlobs * AppConstants.distanceBetweenBlob);
        int blobOffSetY = AppConstants.minBlobOffsetY +
                          random.nextInt(AppConstants.maxBlobOffsetY - AppConstants.minBlobOffsetY + 1);
        blobs.get(j).setBlobOffsetY(blobOffSetY);
        blobs.get(j).newScore = true;
    }
    blobs.get(j).setBlobX(blobs.get(j).getBlobX() - AppConstants.blobVelocity);
}
```

Comment: Just in case you want to practice that upvoting thing .. have fun doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing the relevant code, but I guess your problem starts here:

```
blobs.get(j)
```

It seems that your one and only data structure that "knows" blobs is some sort of list. As a consequence, you always have to iterate *all* of them, to then decide which ones are currently in your visible screen.

The answer: think up a more appropriate way of storing that data. You could for example:

- somehow *sort* the blobs in that list (like "geographically"), so that when you find the first one "off screen", you know that you don't have to process any of the subsequent ones
- use multiple lists, so that your blobs are somehow "grouped", so that you immediately only have to loop a smaller group of blobs
- use different data structures, like maps. The key could be some sort of coordinate, the value could be a list of blobs present on that coordinate, so that you can quickly get to affected blobs

But as your question is pretty broad and generic, don't ask for a more specific answer.